# How to make a loop for API calls Constantly?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, discord

I am wondering how do u make a loop for an api call that will keep calling that API, but when I tried making one it didn't work here is the code:

```
while True:
api_requesting = requests.get("https://api.battlemetrics.com/servers/3411152?include=player", headers=headers)
time.sleep(5)

jsoned_api = api_requesting.json()
function = jsoned_api["included"]

names = []
for person in function:
  names.append(person['attributes']['name'])
```

And this is for e to call upon the request, and parsed it to give me the names of each player etc

````
@client.command(name='players')
async def createEmbed(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"{len(names)} players are online currently")
    urString = ""
    for name in names:
      urString = urString + "> " + name + "\n"
    urString = "```" + urString + "```"
    await ctx.send(urString)
````

So I am wondering how will I make a loop for my request it's all the way at the beginning where it says while true: but when I run it the bot doesn't respond, and doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to stop when the bot does not respond:

```
success = True
while success: 
   api_requesting = requests.get("https://api.battlemetrics.com/servers/3411152?include=player", headers=headers)

   # Success is True when the response status code is 200 
   success = api_requesting.status_code==200
```

But if you want to keep making requests, you can try:

```
while True: 
   api_requesting =  requests.get("https://api.battlemetrics.com/servers/3411152?include=player", headers=headers)
   if api_requesting.status_code == 200: 
      # Do something when the bot responds
   else: 
      time.sleep(5)
      # Do something else when the bot does not respond
```